# Storing a Matrix block data in a variable

Tags: matrix, plugin-supertable

Having an issue searching a Matrix field for a block with a certain value and storing the entire block in a variable. Right now it only seems to be storing the `location` value. The `navigations` field is a Super Table.

```
{## looping through matrix blocks works ##}
{% for block in siteNav.navigations %}

    {{ block.location }}

    {% for row in block.navLinks %}
        {{ row.label }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{## set variable via search matrix block only selects location field ##}
{% set utilityNav = siteNav.navigations.location('utility').limit(1) %}

{{ utilityNav.location }}

{% for row in utilityNav.navLinks %}
  {{ row.label }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Having a hard time following this for some reason. I'm guessing your top example works, but the bottom doesn't?  What's the `location` field? Are you getting an error when you try to loop through `utilityNav.navLinks`?

Comment: Sorry about that. You're correct–the top example works. The bottom example only parses the `location` text field in the matrix block. I'm not able to loop through `utilityNav.navLinks` super table field– no errors either.

Comment: *correction. `location` field is a dropdown